# Stuck on XML Validation Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to create an XML file with XSD XML Validation Schema.

But I'm stuck on 'multi line data'. Couldn't solve that problem.

My guideline: https://www.oecd.org/tax/beps/country-by-country-reporting-xml-schema-user-guide-for-tax-administrations-june-2019.pdf
My XSD: https://www.oecd.org/ctp/exchange-of-tax-information/CbC-Schema-v2.0.zip

Looks no problem until here.

But, from XSD schema, I created and XML example. And don't know how can I integrate data below, inside that.

XML example:

```
...
    <ns2:CbcReports>
        <ns2:ResCountryCode>AF</ns2:ResCountryCode>
        <ns2:Summary>
            <ns2:Revenues>
                <ns2:Unrelated currCode="AED">76</ns2:Unrelated>
                <ns2:Related currCode="AED">2949</ns2:Related>
                <ns2:Total currCode="AED">7859</ns2:Total>
            </ns2:Revenues>
            <ns2:ProfitOrLoss currCode="AED">13486</ns2:ProfitOrLoss>
            <ns2:TaxPaid currCode="AED">17364</ns2:TaxPaid>
            <ns2:TaxAccrued currCode="AED">14015</ns2:TaxAccrued>
            <ns2:Capital currCode="AED">19022</ns2:Capital>
            <ns2:Earnings currCode="AED">27690</ns2:Earnings>
            <ns2:NbEmployees>5500</ns2:NbEmployees>
            <ns2:Assets currCode="AED">26679</ns2:Assets>
        </ns2:Summary>
        <ns2:ConstEntities>
            <ns2:ConstEntity>
                <ns2:ResCountryCode>AF</ns2:ResCountryCode>
                <ns2:TIN issuedBy="AF">AABBCCDDEE</ns2:TIN>
                <ns2:IN issuedBy="AF" INType="AABBCCDDEE">AABBCCDDEE</ns2:IN>
                <ns2:Name>AABBCCDDEE</ns2:Name>
                <ns2:Address legalAddressType="OECD301">
                    <ns2:CountryCode>AF</ns2:CountryCode>
                    <ns2:AddressFree>AABBCCDDEE</ns2:AddressFree>
                </ns2:Address>
            </ns2:ConstEntity>
            <ns2:Role>CBC801</ns2:Role>
            <ns2:IncorpCountryCode>AF</ns2:IncorpCountryCode>
            <ns2:BizActivities>CBC501</ns2:BizActivities>
            <ns2:OtherEntityInfo>AABBCCDDEE</ns2:OtherEntityInfo>
        </ns2:ConstEntities>
    </ns2:CbcReports>
...
```

I must have multiline data, and I don't know how can I pass multiline data in this XML.

Data is below, But how can I use that XML like below?

How can I send multiline data?

[image]

Is that the way that I must do?

```
<CbcReports> 
  Italy blablabla
</CbcReports>
<CbcReports> 
  USA blablabla
</CbcReports>
```

Answer (score 0):

This document

```
<CbcReports> 
  Italy blablabla
</CbcReports>
<CbcReports> 
  USA blablabla
</CbcReports>
```

is not a well-formed XML document because it has more than one root tag.

I suggest that you do some background reading about XML and XSD before trying to solve your problem.